# iOS background fetch working on simulator but not physical device

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, background-fetch

Alright so I have successfully implemented the Background fetch. No issues there. The problem that I am having is that the background fetch works differently on simulator and the device.

```
class func doInBackground(completion: () -> Void) {

    let time = NSDate()
    print(time)

    serverPostRequest()
    completion()
}

class func serverPostRequest() {
    if(loopCount < 1) {
        let params = self.formEncodingBuilder()!
        let syncUrl: String = Constants.BASE_SERVER_URL + Constants.SYNC_URL
        do {
            let opt = try HTTP.POST(syncUrl, parameters: params)
            opt.start { response in
                if let err = response.error {
                    print("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                    //also notify app of failure as needed
                    SYNC_STATE = 1
                    SYNCING = false
                }else{
                    let json = JSON(data: response.data)
                    if let success = json["synced"].bool {//synced, all done nothing to do anymore
                        SYNC_STATE = 2
                        SYNCING = false
                    }else {//process data
                        SyncServiceDataSource.dBOperations(json["data"])
                        print("after")
                        serverPostRequest()
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("got an error creating the request: \(error)")
        }
    }else {
        print("Logical error state, check server logs")
        SYNC_STATE = 1
        SYNCING = false
    }

    loopCount++
}


class SyncServiceDataSource : DataSourceProtocol {

static func dBOperations(data: JSON) {
    print("count")
    print(data.count)
}
```

}

Now the output for background fetch is good which is

> 2016-04-20 18:47:12 +0000
>   count
>   19
>   after
>   Logical error state, check server logs

But when i run the same thing on a iphone 5 (actual)device, it only prints the

> 2016-04-20 18:47:12 +0000

nothing at after

> 2016-04-20 18:49:12 +0000

and after

```
SyncServiceDataSource.dBOperations(json["data"])
```

runs or break using debugger

1. It can't be background fetch 30s limit(i think). Although the response is huge, currently i am calling only one request.
2. wrong code.. uh well .. works perfectly in simulator.

p.s the response data is relatively large json

so the question is what am I missing? and why isn't SyncServiceDataSource.dBOperations getting called

Comment: Any change if you print something before `SYNC_STATE = 2`?  (It looks like the only code path where you don't print anything.)